# Why does Intellij show me a warning about my spring profile?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I have started experimenting with Spring profiles and ever since then, I get the occasional warning (I think it's a warning?) on the top of some files, which I noticed don't get managed by Spring
[image]

I have googled but I don't find any information what "what" am I seeing, why do I see it in some files and not others, and what to do about it.

Here is my application-properties.yml if that helps:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    password: root
    username: root
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chatt?serverTimezone=UTC
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
  profiles:
    active:
      - dev
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a warning, but a feature to switch between the active profiles via the top editor panel, it's [documented in IntelliJ IDEA help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html#spring-change-active-profiles):

[image: Change active profiles]

Comment: I guess I thought it was a warning because of the yellow coloring.